# Not able to sorting the react table data

Tags: reactjs, react-table

in react table all the data its showing but when i want to click the header for sorting its throws errors "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops." How to resolve that one

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import { useTable, useSortBy } from "react-table";
import pack from "./pack.json";
export default function App() {
  const COLUMN = [
    {
      Header: "ID",
      accessor: "id"
    },
    {
      Header: "Name",
      accessor: "name"
    },
    {
      Header: "Age",
      accessor: "age"
    }
  ];
  const columns = useMemo(() => {
    COLUMN, [];
  });
  const data = useMemo(() => {
    pack, [];
  });
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns: COLUMN,
      data: pack
    },
    useSortBy
  );

  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getFooterGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                  {column.render("Header")}
                  <span>
                    {column.isSorted ? (column.isSortedDesc ? ">" : "<") : ""}
                  </span>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      ;
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are not returning COLUMN and pack from the useMemo, as they are wrapped in curly braces.

Also, instead of providing the memoized version of columns and data to useTable you're passing in the original variables.

You could instead do something like this:

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import { useTable, useSortBy } from "react-table";
import pack from "./pack.json";

export default function App() {
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "ID",
        accessor: "id"
      },
      {
        Header: "Name",
        accessor: "name"
      },
      {
        Header: "Age",
        accessor: "age"
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const data = useMemo(() => pack, []);

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data
    },
    useSortBy
  );

  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getFooterGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                  {column.render("Header")}
                  <span>
                    {column.isSorted ? (column.isSortedDesc ? ">" : "<") : ""}
                  </span>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      ;
    </>
  );
}
```